# Discrete Mathematics - Proving equality between two Terms - do I need to separate to two cases?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

It is something Basic, But lets Say $A \cup B = B \cup A$
I saw in a video that I have to prove like that:
First of all, of course I have to seperate to: $(A \cup B) \subseteq (B \cup A)$ and the other side as well: $(B \cup A) \subseteq (A \cup B)$
But I mean, inside the two cases, there is another two cases:
Lets say I have to prove this part: $(A \cup B) \subseteq (B \cup A)$
So I have to separate to two different cases:
in which:
$(A \cup B) = \emptyset$
And the other one is:
$(A \cup B) \ne \emptyset$
Is it a must? or I can just show the case of when its $\ne$, which means, I don't have to separate to cases and and just show from the beginning that $(A \cup B) \subseteq (B \cup A)$ and then thats it.
Basically, the $\ne$ of seperation, is a must? it seems like a lot of trouble for a prove.

Comment: The statement $(A\subseteq B)\subseteq (B\subset A)$ doesn't make any sense.  It means "The thing that is 'A is a subset of B' is a subset of the that that is 'B is a subset of A''.  But $A\subseteq B$ is a statement.  It is not a mathematical object.  It can not be a subset or equal to anything. This is like saying "Michael is an elf is happier than Betty is a dwarf".  It just doesn't make sense.

Comment: This is what the solution has... it is also actually make sense. lets say you have to prove an equality of something ( mostly has in calculus, annoying stuff ), you have to show each side of the equality is subset of the other, when you showed that both sides are subsets of each other, it means the equality is good.
Same as in here, I have to show that for each x that belongs in A \subet B, x belong to B \subet\ A. But never mind, that, about the two cases I spoke, with the empty set, does it matter if I dont do those cases? just show the equality?

Comment: Liron, that does not seem to address what fleablood wrote (which is correct; take their analogy to heart). 

Another way to see why we cannot understand what you mean from what you wrote: it is assumed that "⊆" is a relationship between sets. Hence, we know that "A⊆B" means "A is a subset of B." Now note that "A⊆B" is itself not a set, and neither is "B⊆A". Therefore, they cannot be related using "⊆." If you wish to define a way to relate "A⊆B" and "B⊆A" please do!

Comment: Oh I am an I idiot.. I didnt notice I didnt show the Or And signs.. I did subsets instead.. sorry very much for it!! @fleablood

Comment: @cluelessmathematician Sorry!! I just noticed in what you said... I will fix it immediately!

Comment: Totally fine :)

Comment: Sorry, it will take a few minutes to fix it, probably 10minutes or so.

Comment: Alright, fixed it, hope its good now, I double checked and it seems good now.
( And by the way, I changed a bit the question, I didnt want to make any mistakes with lots of words ) - I am a really begineer with latex, thats why.

Comment: I do not see a reason to consider the empty set as a special case.

Comment: I thought so too, In my course they never did it. I never heard of something like that also.
Only saw it now while going back in the materials before a test. So I dont need to do it right? Thanks!